# Cannot Connect to Oracle Thin Database in SoapUI but can in dbVisualizer

Tags: database-connection, connection-string, soapui

I've tried about every different method using the built in jdbc connections and groovy scripts.
I've tried with oracle thin drivers 14, 6, 7, and 8.

My connection string is in the format (changes where user/pass goes depending on where I use it):

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=yes)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host2)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=serviceName)))
```

Getting below errors:

> 1. the network adapter could not establish the connection
> 2. invalid username/password

The user and pass are correct, I've retyped them many times and the same user/pass work in dbVisualizer.

Looking for any suggestions on other things to try.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_network_adapter_could_not_establish_connection.htm

Comment: Thanks! The issue actually was we were using the Service Name and assumed it was the same as the SID.
But we couldn't just throw the Service Name in the SID field. We had to change the template for the oracle thin jdbc driver to jdbc:oracle:thin:<USER>/<PASSWORD>@//<HOST:127.0.0.1>:<PORT:1521>/<SID>. Then everything worked. We had to say <SID> instead of <SERVICE> or something because soapui wouldn't make a field in the ui if we used something other than service. I'll posted something better formatted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out we were actually used the Service Name and not the SID (We only had the service name and assumed it was the correct thing to be used.

So Service Name != SID

But we could not just plug in the Service Name and get it to work because to use the Service Name instead the connection string has to be changed and therefore the jbdc driver template had to be changed (or you could create a new one).

We changed it to:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:<USER>/<PASSWORD>@//<HOST:127.0.0.1>:<PORT:1521>/<SID>
```

The reason we have  on the end and not  (or something similar) is because SoapUI only seemed to recognize  as a field it would make a UI element from when creating a new connection.

After change it to this and entering in the correct information everything worked.